# Function of the Left Medial Prefrontal Cortex

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurology

I am searching for a specific (as specific as is currently known) region of the brain that has a known(?) large role in deductive and inductive reasoning. My research has narrowed me down to the Left Medial Prefrontal Cortex, however the best papers I found are from 2013 or earlier. Do any of you know the current thought on the function of the lMPFC specifically in regards to logical thinking?

References:

[The Neurology of Reasoning (2002)](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaneurology/fullarticle/782167)

[The role of medial prefrontal cortex in early social cognition (2013)](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnhum.2013.00340/full)